# what is the c parameter in this source code?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to know what is the c in the below source code . can you explain me what is it doing ???

```
        private void txtFamilytoSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var db = new LINQDataContext();
        if (txtFamilytoSearch.Text == "")
            gvTable.DataSource = db.MyTables;
        else
            gvTable.DataSource = db.MyTables.Where(c => c.Family.Substring(0, txtFamilytoSearch.Text.Length) == txtFamilytoSearch.Text).Select(c => c);

    }
```

this is some part of C# code in linq tecnology.

thank you ;-)

Comment: See [Lambda Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Linq` `where`, it iterates over every item in the collection and applies the predicate that you provide.

In this case, `c` represents an individual element in the collection `db.MyTables`

Answer (score 1):

It is an identifier for the currently iterated element of your collection. It is the same as if you´d write

```
var result = new List<T>;  // here T is the actual type of your list 

foreach(var c in db.MyTables) 
{ 
    if (c.Family.Substring(0, txtFamilytoSearch.Text.Length) == txtFamilytoSearch.Text) 
    { 
        result.Add(c); 
    }
}
```